# C# Regex of expire date on TextChanged method: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, date, xamarin

I am creating application on Xamarin and on Entry I created this method:

```
private void expiry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var monthCheck = new Regex(@"^(0[1-9]?|1[0-2]?)$");
    var yearCheck = new Regex(@"^(1[6-9]?|2[0-9]?)$");

    var dateParts = expiry.Text.Split('/');
    if (!monthCheck.IsMatch(dateParts[0]) || !yearCheck.IsMatch(dateParts[1]))
    {
        return;
    }

    var year = int.Parse(dateParts[1]);
    var month = int.Parse(dateParts[0]);
    var lastDateOfExpiryMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
    var cardExpiry = new DateTime(year, month, lastDateOfExpiryMonth, 23, 59, 59);

    int sizeLength = 4;
    string tmpText = expiry.Text.Replace("/", "");
    if (tmpText.Length > sizeLength)
    {
        expiry.Text = expiry.Text.Remove(expiry.Text.Length - 1);
        return;
    }

    if (tmpText.Length > 0 && (expiry.Text.Length % 3 == 0) && expiry.Text.Substring(expiry.Text.Length - 1, 1) != "/" && expiry.Text.Substring(expiry.Text.Length - 2, 1) != "/")
    {
        expiry.Text = string.Concat(expiry.Text.Substring(0, expiry.Text.Length - 1), "/", expiry.Text.Substring(expiry.Text.Length - 1, 1));
    }
}
```

On `if (!monthCheck.IsMatch(dateParts[0]) || !yearCheck.IsMatch(dateParts[1]))` I am getting error that Index was outside the bounds, but how it is possible if I added only symbol to my expiry Entry field?

Comment: debug - anyone?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? There's not enough parts in the string, what if the string doesn't contain a `/` ?

Comment: What is a sample text? I'm pretty sure that you should use `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead.

Comment: if (DateParts.Length < 2) return;

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen as you see there will be `/` if you will type 2 symbols exp: 01/17

Comment: Yes, *when* you have typed all those characters, but the `TextChanged` event fires as soon as you start typing, and at the very first time it fires the text control will be empty. Please debug your code and you should see this.

Comment: @TimSchmelter where exactly I have to add this?

Comment: @BinaryTie: you still haven't added a sample date. What can `expiry.Text` be?

Comment: @TimSchmelter well, it could be 01/17 for example

Comment: @BinaryTie: and what datetime is that? January 2017?

Comment: @TimSchmelter it is January 2017

Comment: @BinaryTie: just out of interest, what are you doing in the lines that start with `int sizeLength = 4;`? That's weird code, maybe we can help to simplify this.

Comment: @TimSchmelter it is size of Entry field. Entry could be maximum 4 characters only

Comment: @BinaryTie: i've asked what you are doing in _the lines that start with..._. The line `int sizeLength = 4;` is the only one that is clear.

Comment: @TimSchmelter after size declaration I am checking size of Entry field if it is bigger than 4 characters I delete it. In next if statement I am checking length of Entry , if entry size is dividable by 3, that mean I am adding programmaticly  `/` after month input .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you every one for help and suggestions, but unfortunately I solved it in other way: first of all I check does `dateParts` is more than 0 , instead check `(dateParts.Length < 2)` . My final code looks like this:

```
var dateParts = expiry.Text.Split('/');
if(dateParts.Length>0)
            {
               if(!monthCheck.IsMatch(dateParts[0]) && dateParts[0] != "")
                {
                    if (dateParts[0].Length > 0)
                        dateParts[0] = dateParts[0].Substring(0, dateParts[0].Length - 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(dateParts[0].Length==2)
                        dateParts[0] = dateParts[0]+ "/";     
                }

                if(dateParts.Length > 1)
                {
                    if (!yearCheck.IsMatch(dateParts[1]) && dateParts[1] != "")
                    {
                        if (dateParts[1].Length > 0)
                            dateParts[1] = dateParts[1].Substring(0, dateParts[1].Length - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method *ExpDate_TextChanged* is getting called as soon someone enters the first character into the TextField and it's getting called for each following character. I guess it's empty by default, so the first call of this method happens while there is not yet a "/" in the TextField.

Move the code which is currently in *ExpDate_TextChanged* to a *Button* for example, so it's executed when the input is complete. And add a sanity check before accessing any of the elements in *dateParts*:

```
if (dateParts.Length < 2)
   return;
}
```

Please note there are better methods for parsing dates like *DateTime.TryParse()* which I highly recommend.

Comment: Actually I need instantly checking of date format, not when Entry field is completed.

Comment: Adding that check of dateParts.Length will fix it anyway.

Comment: Where exactly I have to add this sanity check?

Comment: After "var dateParts = expiry.Text.Split('/');"

Answer (score 0):

Me:

> You still haven't added a sample date. What can expiry.Text be?

You:

> well, it could be 01/17 for example

If that is January 2017 and the expiry time should be: `new DateTime(2017,1,31,23,59,59))`(so the end of that month), you can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime cardExpiry;
bool validDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(expiry.Text, "MM/yy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out cardExpiry);
if (!validDate)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid card expiry month in the format 'MM/yy', for example 01/17");
    return;
}
cardExpiry = cardExpiry.AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1); // last date of month, 23:59:59
// ...
```

Comment: But first I need to check does month is valid from regex. for example 13/17 is not valid.

Comment: @BinaryTie: sorry, there was a bug. Use `MM/yy`. Fixed it in my code. `dd/yy` means first the date and then the year(which means always january), now it checks month/year.

Comment: Yes , I did. But your code is going after regex validation check. First I am checking does month and year pass regex condition and then it moves for example to your code.

Comment: @BinaryTie: look at my last comment. You also don't need regex, my code replaces all your code until the line `int sizeLength = 4;`